# How do you make a better seo friendly URL when there is UTF-8 characters and many space in between?

Tags: url, utf-8, slug

When someone by mistake enters many spaces between characters what I do is to replace all spaces with - but what if there are many spaces in between? for e.g:

User entered post title:

```
فارسی   * Allposts---
```

When I convert the above example to user-friendly url (slug) I get this:

```
----فارسی---*-Allposts---
```

How to put one - for spaces and remove special characters and preserve utf-8 characters as well? The output I'm seeking for is as below:

```
فارسی-Allposts
```

Is there a way to handle it with regex? if positive, how?

---

**EDIT:**

Now I can manage multiple spaces as below:

```
 $string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $string);
```

but for special chars problem still remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove special characters:  replace [\-\?\*] or whatever your blacklist characters are with empty string.
2. Convert strings of whitespace to a single - character: replace \s+ with -

Looks like you already figured out step 2.  Make sure you do it second so you don't accidentally remove your own hyphens that you just inserted.